# How to normalize / equalize background to make gradient more uniform

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, gradient, background

Here's the situation: I'm designing a banner for a client. He provided me a `png` file that has a gradient background. My banner is larger (wider) than the content provided so I have to recreate the background myself.

[image: image problem]

If you watch the above image closely, you will notice that there is a slight colour difference somewhere in the middle of the image.

Is there a command in Photoshop (up to the latest version) that can help me "normalize" the background so that it looks smooth? I have tried the "content-aware fill" but that didn't really work. Is there any other way?

Comment: Hi Luca, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Try use the gaussian blur

Comment: I'd simply redraw the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

To edit a gradient and its "smoothness" as it transitions from one color to another, you'll have to edit it. If you have created the gradient as a layer effect or as a shape fill, find the "Scale" slider. Jiggle this around and you can find desired smoothness of your gradient.